# Python 3 - Как напечатать строку в той же строке перед input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, input

Как напечатать строку в той же строке перед input?
Я пробовал так:

```py
input_start = '> '
input_end = ' <'
input(input_start + '' + input_end)
```

Но это не помогло. Я написал "Привет мир", и вместо этого:

```bsh
> Привет мир <
```

появилось вот это:

```bsh
>  <Привет мир
```

Кто-нибудь знает,
как это реализовать?

Comment: `input('> Привет мир <')` выдало
`> Привет мир <`

Comment: Если после этого что-то написать, то это не решает проблему. Например:
`input('> Привет мир <')` - код; `> Привет мир < [тут будет ввод]` - консоль;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызовите `input()` внутри `print()`:

```py
print('> ' + input() + ' <')
```

Результат:

```
> Привет мир <
```

---

Однако, полностью запретить `input()` переносить строку после ввода не получится.
Почитать почему, можно [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line).

Но, если это сильно необходимо, самое простое, что можно сделать - очищать консоль:

```
import os

def raw_input(start, end):
    inp = input(start)
    os.system('clear || cls || :') #проверка на OS
    print('> ' + inp + ' <')

raw_input('> ', ' <')
```

Но это действие будет стирать все предыдущие строки.

---

Или можно использовать модуль `getpass`, который будет скрывать ввод, но все равно оставит пустую строку:

```
import getpass

def raw_input(start, end):
    inp = getpass.getpass('')
    print('> ' + inp + ' <')

raw_input('> ', ' <')
```

---

Еще один вариант описан **[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436173/14519908)** - достаточно сложная реализация, но весь код можно поместить в отдельный файл и импортировать. Работает именно так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Это работает, но сначала нужно ввести `строку`, а потом только это выведется на экран.

Comment: @Brainsluggy дополнил ответ

Comment: В целом всё работает :)

Comment: @Brainsluggy кажется нашел то, что вам надо, сейчас еще дополню, взгляните

Comment: Работает. Благодарен :)